# Object design for create new user

Tags: java, oop

I'm facing this week a problem, so I decided to use an approach that I'm not sure is right. So I need your help to help me understand what I'm possibly doing wrong.

I have two types of users: Internal and outsourced, they have some attributes that differs one of the other. What I think to do was.

So I created a employee class, that aggregate all the common attributes

```
public abstract class Employee {

private String name;
private String address;
private String telephone;
private String cpf;
private Integer age;
```

A outsourced class that have 2 more attributes

```
public class Outsourced extends Employee {

private String companyName;
private Date endDate;}
```

And a Internal for internal users.

```
public class Internal extends Employee {}
```

Is it right to have this internal class or I should use the employee for the internals? have a class with no attributes seems to be wrong to me, but at the same time I think that use the employee class for internal user to generic, if one day we create a new kind of user we my have some problems.

Anyway thanks for any help :)

Comment: By the way, the terrible `Date` and `Calendar` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. You likely want `LocalDate` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fine to me. With this approach, you have an easily extensible business model if one day you have the need to either add some common property to all types of Employees (by adding it to `Employee`), add some new property to either `Outsourced` or `Internal` or even creating a new type of Employee (by extending the abstract `Employee`). I would say you are good to go and continue your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely right.

Firstly,  you could want append some special logic or fields to `Internal` later. `staffNumber` e.g.. Existence of a separate class lets too easy deal it.

Secondly,  you could want separated  `Internal` from `Outsourced` instances in your code some time.